# GoCD config-repo schedules pipeline on change which I don't want

Tags: config, pipeline, go-cd

GoCD config-repo schedules pipeline on change in pipeline code but I only want that pipeline to trigger via change in specified material of the pipeline.

Any solutions to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not aware of blacklist/whitelist concept in GoCD. So using blacklist over config-repo solved my problem.